# Is a site with html and javascript secure

Tags: javascript, html, css, security

IF: I write a site in HTML5, Javascript and CSS3.
It has no forms or any input other than mouse clicks on links. No logins.
No messaging. No comments.
Will this site have vulnerabilities?

For the 2nd time in a month, I've been notified by my host there are files
with malicious code (PHP and Wordpress files) that I need to clean.

Since the last cleaning knocked out the site, I'd like to just rip
all PHP and Wordpress out and just hand code it.  Excluding someone
hacking into my accounts control panel or FTP will my code be vulnerable to change or injection?

Comment: "_I've been notified by my host_" are you certain it's from your host but not someone who's phishing you?

Comment: They notified me by email, but I contacted them by known good phone number. They turned the site access back on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will most likely be safe as far as your files, but it can still be hacked if the server exposes some kind of scripts that you're not aware of and don't have any control over, or if it runs unpatched versions of OS/Web server/etc. If another hack happens and you don't have any scripts, then you'll know it's the provider's fault, not yours.

Some providers offer Wordpress installations that they control, you might try that instead of installing and maintaining it yourself.

Comment: That's what I thought.  I like being able to show it is not my code making issues.

Answer (score 1):

It honestly just depends on the security of the server you are using to host all your files, and how it is configured. Your files alone aren't malicious; however, if an unauthorized entity was to gain access to your control panel for your server/hosting they can then embed/upload malicious code that will affect you and your users. Therefore, one should take extra care in making sure that their hosting account/server takes precautions to mitigate intrusions. Whether this is on the user end (creating strong passwords and maybe even two-factor authentication) as well as on the code/maintainer's end (keeping up-to-date on coding best practices and taking steps to disallow rogue incoming connections).

Here is a good overview of what I am taking about: http://www.instantshift.com/2011/02/11/a-guide-to-web-hosting-security-issues-and-prevention/

Since you aren't using a whole lot of server-side communication, you should be fine as long as you are following the best Javascript practices and making any connections in a secure manner. But you should take another look at securing your control panel.

Comment: It's a shared hosting server. If I understand the linked article, it is saying malicious code on one shared site can spread onto all of them.